# Problem with binding properties in laravel

Tags: laravel, request

I try to change property using:

```
$request->merge(['state' => $state_from_database->name]);
```

and when I Log all request using:

```
\Log::info($request->all())
```

it shows me valid 'state' in request. But if I

```
\Log::info($request->get('state'))
```

it's empty string but

```
\Log::info($request->state)
```

returns me valid state name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$request->request->add(['state' => $state_from_database->name]);
```

and then you can use it as,

```
\Log::info($request('state'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$request['state'] = $state_from_database->name
```

After that you can get stat by this

```
dd($request->get('state'));
```

OR

```
dd($request->input('state'));
```

Both ways will work properly